# Reduce score while time passing

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm working on a quiz with several questions. De score of an answer is based on the time the user needs to answer the question.
By example:
Maximum score is 20 points. After 3 seconds it's reduced to 15 points. And after 6 extra seconds it is 5 points.
I'm not quite sure how to set it up. I stumbled on setTimeout(), but what's the exact code to use?

Thanks!

Comment: I would take the timestamp the question has started and the timestamp it was answered and get the diff. Then you just have to calculate the points:
if (diff <= 3) score += 20 else if ....

Comment: Okay. Just a little remark: I want to preview the score live updated.

Answer (score 1):

As Muhammed B. Aydemir already said in the comments, you can use the time difference to calculate the score at any point in time.

In order to update the score live, you can use `requestAnimationFrame()`.

```js
const span = document.getElementById("score-span"),
meter = document.getElementById("score-meter");

const startTime = Date.now();

function getScore() {
  return 20 - (Date.now() - startTime) / 600;
}

requestAnimationFrame(function updateScore() {
  const score = Math.max(getScore(), 0);
  span.innerText = score.toFixed(1);
  meter.value = score;
  
  if (score > 0)
     requestAnimationFrame(updateScore);
});
```

```css
#score-span {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
Score: <span id="score-span"></span> <meter id="score-meter" min="0" low="5" max="20">
```

If you want to update the score in discrete units, you can also use timers:

```js
const span = document.getElementById("score-span"),
meter = document.getElementById("score-meter");

let score = 20;

function updateScore() {
  span.innerText = score.toFixed(1);
  meter.value = score;
  
  if (score === 0)
     clearInterval(updateScoreIntervalId);

  score = Math.max(score - 5, 0);
}

const updateScoreIntervalId = setInterval(updateScore, 3000);
updateScore();
```

```css
#score-span {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
Score: <span id="score-span"></span> <meter id="score-meter" min="0" low="7.5" max="20">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and reply! But in this case it will continuously reduce the score? Because in my example, it should go by steps 20 to 15 to 5 points. Nothing in between...

Comment: Well, in that case you could use `setInterval`/`setTimeout` and decrease the score by 5 each time. I'm going to add that to  my answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the effort. It isn't quite exactly what I'm looking for...
1) I don't want to use a meter. Just text.
2) I just want these steps: 20 - 15 - 5. And if possible, I want to choose how many seconds there are between the different steps.

Comment: This is just an example. You can edit the interval by changing `3000` to something else.